# Upload base64 image to .NET webservice and convert it there

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, base64

I have a function that sends data through `data:JSON.stringify(formdata)`using POST to a remove .NET webservice. I have no problem this far. What I want to do it to add also add a another value to the formdata JSON that will hold a base64 image data and send it to the server, and there I will convert it back to a JPEG image.

How can I so that? I already have a preview function that created a preview, but also create a base64 image:

```
function previewFile() {
    var preview = document.querySelector('.uploadimage');
    var file = document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.addEventListener("load", function () {
        preview.src = reader.result;
    }, false);

    if (file) {
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
}
```

I see many question people asking how to upload image to the server. I want to stay with the current configuration but just pass the base64 image data to the server as a string. I see many developers struggling with that, and most of them just engine up creating a form in javascript and submitting like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a recent way I did this:

```
string base64 = base64string.Substring(base64string.IndexOf(',') + 1);
byte[] imageData = Convert.FromBase64String(base64);
Image img;
using (var ms = new MemoryStream(imageData, 0, imageData.Length)) {
img = Image.FromStream(ms, true);
```

You will need:

```
using System.Drawing;
```

OR to simply convert to a jpg, use this:

```
File.WriteAllBytes("image.jpeg", Convert.FromBase64String(base64));
```

For sending the data I use the following JS:

```
function sendImage() {
    if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
        var FR = new FileReader();
        FR.onload = function (e) {
            $("#imgImage").attr("src", e.target.result); //show a preview
            //send e.target.result as a string to your webservice
        };
        FR.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
    }
}
```

I use this event to listen for uploaded files:

```
document.getElementById("fileid").addEventListener("change", sendImage, false);
```

And the front end:

```
<input type="file" id="fileid" />
```

Comment: Thanks. That's the .NET code, how can I transfer the data correctly to the webservice via a parameter attached to the formdata JSON?

Comment: @IdanShechter I post back the value in e.target.result, so i am not using JSON, but you should be able to use that value

Comment: What is the fileid ? You share partial code, so I try to understand it piece by piece.

Comment: @IdanShechter Sorry, fileid would be the id of your file input field. So for example: <input type="file" id="fileid" />

Comment: Thanks, I will follow the answer, it makes sense. I will work it out the same as you did. Thanks a lot for your time my friend.

Comment: @IdanShechter Great glad i could help